# Imprimir objeto enviado desde javascript via ajax a php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Desde Ajax, mando lo siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
              data:  formData, //send data via AJAX
              url:   'controller/ctrlPago.php', //url file controller PHP
              dataType:'json',
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              type:  'post', //send POST data
              success:function(response) { //get request

                if(response.success){ 
                  //
                  //alert("Ya llegamos a la respuesta :) + status: " + response.status );
                  hideLoad();
                }else{
                  //

                }
                

                //CONFIRM MODAL/ALERT

                //$('.confirm').toast('show');      
              }
            });
```

Dentro de *formData*, tenemos a *products* que contiene lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cambia dependiendo el número de productos que envíen.

Cuando envio los datos desde Ajax, el contenido de *products* que es el array de productos, se ve así en los Headers:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiere decir, que lleva 3 productos, pero una vez que los recibo en PHP, no me ha sido posible obtener la info de vuelta.

Intente lo siguiente:

```
echo " LIST OF PRODUCTS: " . $_POST["products"];
print_r($_POST["products"]);
$products = json_decode($_POST['products'], true);
print_r($products);

$dataProducts=$_POST["products"];
            foreach($dataProducts as $value){
                $json = json_decode($value);

                echo $json->id;
            }
```

Y no lo he logrado, no se si tengan alguna recomendación. Quiero obtener el conjunto de ID de productos, para insertar mi detalle de productos en la tabla.

Comment: En el formData que guardas ? un formulario ? O agregas cosas con .append ?? Es necesario saber esto, para que puedas recibirlo de la manera correcta en php

Comment: Es un arreglo que creo vía arrayCart.push({nombre:nombre_producto, precio:precio_producto, cantidad: cantidad, id: id});

Comment: y luego en formData.append('products', arrayCart);

Comment: Realiza un **echo var_dump($_POST["products"])**  y me dices que es lo que te muestra

Comment: Obtengo esto string(133) "[{"nombre":"Pasta de Carne","precio":666,"cantidad":"1","id":"3"},{"nombre":"Pasta Fetuchinni","precio":120,"cantidad":"1","id":"2"}]" solo si en JS hago esto: var productString = JSON.stringify(arrayCart); SINO HAGO ESO, obtengo esto: string(31) "[object Object],[object Object]"

Comment: Bien tiene toda la pinta de un **json** ahora cuando haces el **json_decode** ya estarías en condiciones de recorrer: foreach($products as $obj){
        $id_product = $obj->id;
        echo $id_product;}  intenta hacer lo siguiente y me dices que te muestra

Comment: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in $obj->id; (Es lo que me responde el PHP)

Comment: ando haciendo pruebas con $id_product = $obj['id'].'\n'; , segun yo ya salio el ID, deja confirmo

Comment: Obtuve *123* de respuesta al escribir: foreach($products as $obj){ 
    $id_product = $obj['id']; 
    echo $id_product;
   }

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode` recibe un objeto, en cambio esta recibiendo un array de objetos.

```
 $array = ['{"nombre":"nombretest", "precio":"455t", "cantidad": 44, "id": 2}',
'{"nombre":"nombretest2", "precio":"333", "cantidad": 22, "id": 5}'];
    foreach($array as &$value){
        $json = json_decode($value);
    
    echo $json->id;
    }
```

de esta forma deberías poder acceder sin problemas

Comment: Me sale esto: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - PHP $dataProducts=$_POST["products"]; foreach($dataProducts as $value){
    $json = json_decode($value);

    echo $json->id;
   }

Comment: Solo asi hermano, foreach($products as $obj){ $id_product = $obj['id']; echo $id_product; } gracias por tu ayuda.